# macOS bundled application is quitting on startup

Tags: macos, go

I have a Go app that I would like to bundle into a macOS app. It functions as a backend REST server for other components, so it would run in the background, without a UI component.

I have manually built out the standard bundle structure, and added the compiled binary and a fairly generic plist.info. I then signed it with `codesign -f -o runtime --timestamp -s "FOO123" myapp.app` (values replaced).

When I double click the bundle, the app seems to open, but it does not actually show up as running (in eg the activity monitor).

When I examine the console.app logs, I see that the app process terminates almost immediately on launch (logs below). There is no obvious error thrown.

If I double click the binary from within the bundle, it works correctly.

What I have tried:

- looking at permissions and pathing
- modifying values in the plist (below)
- looked at dependencies with otool (I believe there are only system level ones)

What might be causing this behaviour? How might I go about debugging it?

Thanks

Info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
  <string>myapp</string>
  <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
  <string>myapp</string>
  <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>ca.myorg.myapp.test</string>
  <key>CFBundleName</key>
  <string>myapp</string>
  <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
  <string>icon.icns</string>
  <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
  <string>0.01</string>
  <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
  <string>6.0</string>
  <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
  <string>APPL</string>
  <key>IFMajorVersion</key>
  <integer>0</integer>
  <key>IFMinorVersion</key>
  <integer>1</integer>
  <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key><true/>
  <key>NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching</key><true/>
  <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
  <key>LSBackgroundOnly</key><true/>
  <key>LSUIElement</key><true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

console.app logs

```
default 11:45:24.843571-0400    runningboardd   Launch request for app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>[0] is using uid 501 (divined from auid 501 euid 501)
default 11:45:24.843677-0400    runningboardd   Acquiring assertion targeting app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)> from originator [osservice<com.apple.Finder(501)>:589] with description <RBSAssertionDescriptor| "LS launch ca.myorg.myapp.test" ID:216-589-16074 target:app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)> attributes:[
    <RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.launchservicesd" name:"LaunchRoleBackground" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">
    ]>
default 11:45:24.843774-0400    runningboardd   Assertion 216-589-16074 (target:app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>) will be created as active
default 11:45:24.844048-0400    runningboardd   Executing launch request for app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)> (LS launch ca.myorg.myapp.test)
default 11:45:24.844094-0400    runningboardd   Checking PreventLaunch: global:0 exPath:/Users/dave/dev/ixmaps/ctrd/trgen-macos/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp predicates:(null) allow:(null)
default 11:45:24.844142-0400    runningboardd   Creating and launching job for: app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>
default 11:45:24.844172-0400    runningboardd   _mutateContextIfNeeded called for ca.myorg.myapp.test
default 11:45:24.844367-0400    runningboardd   app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>: -[RBPersonaManager personaForIdentity:context:personaUID:personaUniqueString:] required 0.000954 ms (wallclock); resolved to {4294967295, (null)}
default 11:45:24.844590-0400    runningboardd   'app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>' Constructed job description:
<dictionary: 0x7f90fc43ffa0> { count = 22, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
    "Platform" => <int64: 0xc0fa8f1dd96cf4f3>: 1
    "ProcessType" => <string: 0x7f90fe960710> { length = 3, contents = "App" }
    "EnableTransactions" => <bool: 0x7ff84ed54270>: false
    "_ManagedBy" => <string: 0x7f90fe95c480> { length = 22, contents = "com.apple.runningboard" }
    "CFBundleIdentifier" => <string: 0x7f90fe95fc20> { length = 26, contents = "ca.myorg.myapp.test" }
    "_ResourceCoalition" => <string: 0x7f90fe94ac30> { length = 66, contents = "app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>" }
    "ThrottleInterval" => <int64: 0xc0fa88e2269314f3>: 2147483647
    "MachServices" => <dictionary: 0x7f90fe95d130> { count = 0, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
    }
    "EnablePressuredExit" => <bool: 0x7ff84ed54270>: false
    "LimitLoadToSessionType" => <array: 0x7f90fe960580> { count = 2, capacity = 8, contents =
        0: <string: 0x7f90fe959270> { length = 4, contents = "Aqua" }
        1: <string: 0x7f90fe9592a0> { length = 11, contents = "LoginWindow" }
    }
    "InitialTaskRole" => <int64: 0xc0fa8f1dd96c84f3>: 6
    "EnvironmentVariables" => <dictionary: 0x7f90fe965020> { count = 13, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
        "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING" => <string: 0x7f90fe960550> { length = 14, contents = "0x1F5:0x0:0x52" }
        "TMPDIR" => <string: 0x7f90fe946100> { length = 49, contents = "/var/folders/f0/y2h0804d279_7vtl8q2rzh3r0000gn/T/" }
        "SHELL" => <string: 0x7f90fe95aff0> { length = 8, contents = "/bin/zsh" }
        "HOME" => <string: 0x7f90fe95b590> { length = 12, contents = "/Users/colin" }
        "SSH_AUTH_SOCK" => <string: 0x7f90fe9635e0> { length = 51, contents = "/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.tqLqMuaovT/Listeners" }
        "DISPLAY" => <string: 0x7f90fe937ed0> { length = 55, contents = "/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.BnlzHuNeHm/org.xquartz:0" }
        "LOGNAME" => <string: 0x7f90fe95caf0> { length = 5, contents = "colin" }
        "PATH" => <string: 0x7f90fe957ea0> { length = 29, contents = "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin" }
        "XPC_SERVICE_NAME" => <string: 0x7f90fe95afc0> { length = 16, contents = "com.apple.Finder" }
        "__CFBundleIdentifier" => <string: 0x7f90fe941d60> { length = 26, contents = "ca.myorg.myapp.test" }
        "COMMAND_MODE" => <string: 0x7f90fe957700> { length = 8, contents = "unix2003" }
        "USER" => <string: 0x7f90fe95af60> { length = 5, contents = "colin" }
        "XPC_FLAGS" => <string: 0x7f90fe937ea0> { length = 3, contents = "0x0" }
    }
    "_AdditionalProperties" => <dictionary: 0x7f90fc406bd0> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
        "RunningBoard" => <dictionary: 0x7f90fc44ded0> { count = 4, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
            "TMPDIR" => <string: 0x7f90fc441d10> { length = 49, contents = "/var/folders/f0/y2h0804d279_7vtl8q2rzh3r0000gn/T/" }
            "HOME" => <string: 0x7f90fc44e2d0> { length = 12, contents = "/Users/colin" }
            "RunningBoardLaunchedIdentity" => <dictionary: 0x7f90fc410820> { count = 5, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
                "AJL" => <string: 0x7f90fc4254c0> { length = 56, contents = "application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448" }
                "TYPE" => <int64: 0xc0fa8f1dd96cf4f3>: 1
                "AUID" => <uint64: 0xc0fa8f1dd973b4e3>: 501
                "EAI" => <string: 0x7f90fc44ea50> { length = 26, contents = "ca.myorg.myapp.test" }
                "PLAT" => <uint64: 0xc0fa8f1dd96cf4e3>: 1
            }
            "RunningBoardLaunched" => <bool: 0x7ff84ed54250>: true
        }
    }
    "ExitTimeOut" => <int64: 0xc0fa8f1dd96cf4f3>: 1
    "Label" => <string: 0x7f90fe957340> { length = 56, contents = "application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448" }
    "WaitForDebugger" => <bool: 0x7ff84ed54250>: true
    "MaterializeDatalessFiles" => <bool: 0x7ff84ed54250>: true
    "WorkingDirectory" => <string: 0x7f90fe95fb60> { length = 1, contents = "/" }
    "_LaunchType" => <int64: 0xc0fa8f1dd96cd4f3>: 3
    "AbandonProcessGroup" => <bool: 0x7ff84ed54250>: true
    "ProgramArguments" => <array: 0x7f90fe941fd0> { count = 1, capacity = 8, contents =
        0: <string: 0x7f90fe95c610> { length = 101, contents = "/Users/dave/dev/ixmaps/ctrd/trgen-macos/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp" }
    }
    "Program" => <string: 0x7f90fe9594f0> { length = 101, contents = "/Users/dave/dev/ixmaps/ctrd/trgen-macos/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp" }
}
default 11:45:24.853820-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003] Memory Limits: active 0 inactive 0
 <private>
default 11:45:24.853863-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003] This process will not be managed.
default 11:45:24.853893-0400    runningboardd   Now tracking process: [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003]
default 11:45:24.854012-0400    runningboardd   Calculated state for app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>: running-active (role: Background)
default 11:45:24.854222-0400    runningboardd   Using default underlying assertion for app: [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003]
default 11:45:24.854443-0400    runningboardd   Acquiring assertion targeting [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003] from originator [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003] with description <RBSAssertionDescriptor| "RB Underlying Assertion" ID:216-216-16075 target:22003 attributes:[
    <RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.underlying" name:"defaultUnderlyingAppAssertion" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">,
    <RBSAcquisitionCompletionAttribute| policy:AfterApplication>
    ]>
default 11:45:24.854722-0400    runningboardd   Assertion 216-216-16075 (target:[app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003]) will be created as active
default 11:45:24.855138-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003] reported to RB as running
default 11:45:24.855618-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003] Ignoring jetsam update because this process is not memory-managed
default 11:45:24.855623-0400    runningboardd   Calculated state for app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>: running-active (role: Background)
default 11:45:24.855670-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003] Ignoring suspend because this process is not lifecycle managed
default 11:45:24.855815-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003] Set darwin role to: Background
default 11:45:24.856146-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003] Ignoring GPU update because this process is not GPU managed
default 11:45:24.856499-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003] Ignoring memory limit update because this process is not memory-managed
default 11:45:24.858537-0400    loginwindow -[ApplicationManager checkInAppContext:eventData:] | ApplicationManager: Checked in app : myapp
default 11:45:24.857773-0400    runningboardd   Acquiring assertion targeting [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003] from originator [osservice<com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd>:138] with description <RBSAssertionDescriptor| "backgroundApp:22003" ID:216-138-16076 target:22003 attributes:[
    <RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.launchservicesd" name:"RoleNonUserInteractive" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">
    ]>
default 11:45:24.858405-0400    runningboardd   Assertion 216-138-16076 (target:[app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003]) will be created as active
default 11:45:24.860124-0400    runningboardd   Calculated state for app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>: running-active (role: NonUserInteractive)
default 11:45:24.862251-0400    Finder  LAUNCH: 0x0-0xf3af3a ca.myorg.myapp.test starting stopped process.
default 11:45:24.864088-0400    runningboardd   Invalidating assertion 216-589-16074 (target:app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>) from originator [osservice<com.apple.Finder(501)>:589]
default 11:45:24.867717-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003] Ignoring jetsam update because this process is not memory-managed
default 11:45:24.867748-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003] Ignoring suspend because this process is not lifecycle managed
default 11:45:24.867786-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003] Set darwin role to: NonUserInteractive
default 11:45:24.867810-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003] Ignoring GPU update because this process is not GPU managed
default 11:45:24.867820-0400    runningboardd   Successfully acquired underlying assertion for [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003]
default 11:45:24.868019-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003] Ignoring memory limit update because this process is not memory-managed
default 11:45:24.971609-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003] Ignoring jetsam update because this process is not memory-managed
default 11:45:24.971632-0400    runningboardd   Calculated state for app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>: running-active (role: NonUserInteractive)
default 11:45:24.971643-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003] Ignoring suspend because this process is not lifecycle managed
default 11:45:24.971668-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003] Ignoring GPU update because this process is not GPU managed
default 11:45:24.971745-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003] Ignoring memory limit update because this process is not memory-managed
default 11:45:25.385469-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003] termination reported by launchd (0, 0, 256)
default 11:45:25.385550-0400    runningboardd   Removing process: [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003]
default 11:45:25.385838-0400    runningboardd   Removing launch job for: [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003]
default 11:45:25.386179-0400    runningboardd   Removed job for [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003]
default 11:45:25.386238-0400    runningboardd   Removing assertions for terminated process: [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003]
default 11:45:25.390310-0400    runningboardd   Calculated state for app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>: none (role: None)
default 11:45:25.390595-0400    runningboardd   Calculated state for app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>: none (role: None)
default 11:45:25.390947-0400    launchservicesd Hit the server for a process handle 7701219000055f3 that resolved to: [app<application.ca.myorg.myapp.test.12967144.13131448(501)>:22003]
default 11:45:25.392110-0400    loginwindow -[PersistentAppsSupport applicationQuit:] | for app:myapp, _appTrackingState = 2
```

Comment: Did you actually verify your compiled Go binary runs if launched from a shell prompt? For example, I have the Kindle ebook reader on my Mac. I can run it from a shell prompt by doing `cd /Applications/Kindle.app/Contents/MacOS` then `./Kindle`. I haven't bundled any of my Go programs into macOS apps but that would be the first thing I try. It also means any messages from the app will appear in your terminal and if it dies that should be readily apparent.

Comment: What do the launchd logs say? I see it was terminated normally. Some cursory reading indicated background tasks may be stopped by Apple application management processes: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/707643

Comment: Confirmed that I can run the binary from the terminal with ./myapp. It loads and outputs as expected.

Comment: Logs from /private/var/log/com.apple.xpc.launchd/launchd.log here: https://pastebin.com/DxS3gmWd